# Is there any method to show loading widget while retrieving data from Firebase Realtime Database in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

Here is snippet of code for loading data from firebase realtime database to a list:

```
var CategoryName =  FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('CategoryNames').once()
        .then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
      var key  = dataSnapshot.value.keys;
      for(var i in key)
      {
        // print(dataSnapshot.value[i]['Name']);
        CategoriesOnly categoriesOnly = new CategoriesOnly(
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['Name']
        );
        categoriesOnlyList.add(categoriesOnly);
      }
      setState(() {
        print(categoryItemList.length);
      });

    });
```

I'm storing these data into a list and showing them into ListView.builder.
And I want to show the screen once data is fully loaded meanwhile it show some kind of loading widget or loading screen but in my case screen looks blank and after sometime it shows the data. And if internet connectivity is slow blank screen appears for a minutes and loads it(because my data contains images as well). And also I want if loading time exceeds from some specific time it will show try reloading again or internet connectivity error. Please help.

Comment: Look into [`FutureBuilder`s](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: @ChristopherMoore, I'm able to add delay and show loading widget but how do I know when the data is loaded completely. Suppose I've used 5 second delay and someone with great internet speed has to wait for 5 sec and someone with slow internet speed will not able to see data even after 5 sec.

Comment: You should never be purposefully _adding_ delay. There is no real purpose to doing so. As I said you should look into `FutureBuilder`. The current way you are obtaining data from the `Future` is not ideal and messy.

Answer (score 1):

As the other people already said I think the best solution would be a FutureBuilder like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: //your future you want the data from,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text("None");
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text("active");
                case ConnectionState.waiting:  /while you are waiting for the data...
                return CupertinoActivityIndicator(); //thats the typical apple loading
                return CircularProgressIndicator(); // this would be a blue circle
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  //you have the data and can access it with 'snapshot.data'
              }
        }),
```